# For an infinite set, prove that the collection of subsets A such that A is finite, or A complement is finite is a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This problem seems incorrect to me. I proved it for the case where we replace finite with countable, but I don't believe it is true here - a sigma algebra must be closed under countable union - let $\Omega$ be the reals. The integers are formed by the countable union of the individual integers - and their complement is not finite. Just wanted to check my whether my logic makes sense here.

Comment: Yes, if those are the only allowed sets in the potential sigma algebra, then I buy your argument regarding the integers.

Comment: Let $A$ be the even integers, that is a countable union of finite sets. Then neither $A$ nor its complement are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this statement is false, and your counterexample is valid.