# Show that the collection of subsets $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ such that $A$ or $A^{c}$ is finite form an algebra but is not a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I am reviewing probability theory for my final exams in 7-9 weeks, and I am reading Durrett in detail. Then, in measure theory part, Example 1.1.6, he provides an example showing an algebra is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, as follows

> Let $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ = the collection of $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ so that $A$ or $A^{c}$ is finite.

A related post is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326843/for-an-infinite-set-prove-that-the-collection-of-subsets-a-such-that-a-is-finit).

Firstly, I wanted to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, but I got stuck in the end.

Let $A\in\mathcal{A}$, then if $A$ is finite, $(A^{c})^{c}$ is finite which implies that $A^{c}\in\mathcal{A}$, if $A^{c}$ is finite, then $A^{c}\in\mathcal{A}$ immediately.

For $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, if $A, B$ finite, then $A\cup B$ is finite so $A\cup B\in\mathcal{A}$, if $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ are finite, then $(A\cup B)^{c}=A^{c}\cap B^{c}$ is finite, so $(A\cup B)\in\mathcal{A}$.

**But I don't know how to show the case if $A$ is finite but $B^{c}$ is finite (or vice versa). How could I express $A\cup B$ as something with $A$ and $B^{c}$?**

To show it is not a $\sigma$-algebra, consider the collection $\{A_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, where $A_{k}:=\{2k\}$, which is a countable collection of subsets in $\mathcal{A}$, since each $A_{k}$ is finite. Then, $B:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$ is countably infinite, but $B^{c}$ includes all the odd numbers which is also infinite. Thus, $B\notin\mathcal{A}$, and thus $\mathcal{A}$ is not closed under countable union.

Is my proof right? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $(A\cup B)^c = A^c\cap B^c \subseteq B^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$

1.If $B$ is finite and  $A$ not finite(thus $A^c$ is finite) then $(B \cup A)^c=A^c \cap B^c \subseteq A^c$ is finite thus $A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$

2.If $B$ is not finite and $A$ is finite  do the same as $1.$

If one of the $A^c,B^c$ is finite  then use that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$ in every case.

Comment: is my argument of $\mathcal{A}$ not being $\sigma$-algebra correct?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical... Yes it is correct!

Comment: Thank you so much!